# Physics engine :calculating delta time

Tags: game-physics, physics, physics-engine

I am building a physics engine in C.
How to compute time difference with high precision between frames (deltatime) in C ?(I am not using any graphics api)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct timespec t1, t2; 
    long delta_t = 0;

    while(1)  {
        printf("delta_t = %d nanoseconds\n", delta_t);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t1);

        // do something

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t2);
        delta_t = (t2.tv_nsec - t1.tv_nsec);
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

*The example tested with GCC 8.1.0.*